# unixODBC on Mac OS X (via brew) and PHP

Tags: php, macos, odbc, unixodbc, mdbtools

I'm trying to work with ODBC on a Mac OS X 10.14 comp.

My devel env have a nginx webserver and php 7.3.10.
After following some guides, I've installed `mdbtools` with odbc support.

I can read my access database with `isql`, via odbc name or DSN.

```
Command: isql -v -k "Driver=MDBTools;DBQ=/database.accdb;"
Command: isql -v MyODBOrigin
```

Using both connection commands, `isql` connects OK, and I can use a `SELECT * FROM MyTable` to see data.

### Now, the problems:

#### Using PHP `odbc_connect`:

```
$connection = odbc_connect('MyODBCOrigin', '', '');
$res = odbc_exec($connection, 'SELECT * FROM MyTable');
while(odbc_fetch_row($res)){
    for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($res);$i++){
        echo "Result is ".odbc_result($res,$i);
    }
}
```

PHP Error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 21474836512 bytes) in /web/odbc.php on line 34
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  410408  {main}( )   .../odbc.php:0
2   0.5053  434576  odbc_result ( ) .../odbc.php:34
```

#### Using PDO:

```
$connection = new \PDO('odbc:MyODBCOrigin');
$connection = new \PDO('Driver=MDBTools;DBQ=/database.accdb;');
```

Using both connection methods causes odbc to die (nginx returns a 404 error).

ODBC Trace:

```
[ODBC][31713][1570202266.779582][__handles.c][460]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Environment = 0x7f8844001200 [ODBC][31713][1570202266.779895][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
                Entry:
                        Environment = 0x7f8844001200
                        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
                        Value = 0x3
                        StrLen = 0 [ODBC][31713][1570202266.779998][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][381]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS] [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780138][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
                Entry:
                        Environment = 0x7f8844001200
                        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_CP_MATCH
                        Value = 0x0
                        StrLen = 0 [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780217][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][381]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS] [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780316][SQLAllocHandle.c][377]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 2
                        Input Handle = 0x7f8844001200 [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780419][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Output Handle = 0x7f8844008a00 [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780493][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][399]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x7f8844008a00
                        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT
                        Value = 0x1
                        StrLen = -6 [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780562][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][691]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS] [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780625][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][399]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x7f8844008a00
                        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_CURSORS
                        Value = 0x0
                        StrLen = -6 [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780684][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][691]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS] [ODBC][31713][1570202266.780752][SQLConnect.c][3721]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x7f8844008a00
                        Server Name = [MyODBCOrigin][length = 7 (SQL_NTS)]
                        User Name = [NULL]
                        Authentication = [NULL]
                UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'US-ASCII' and UNICODE 'UCS-2-INTERNAL'
```

#### Configuration used for tests:

My `odbc.ini`:

```
[MyODBCOrigin]
Description = Example
Driver = MDBTools
Servername = localhost
Database = /database.accdb
UserName =
Password =
port = 5432
```

My `odbcinst.ini`:

```
[ODBC]
Trace = 1
TraceFile = /tmp/odbctrace.log

[MDBTools]
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libmdbodbc.dylib
Setup  =
```

Anyone can help me with this problem?

#### EDIT

I've found [this "bug report" on mdbtools repository](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/issues/85). That seems to be the same problem. I've tried the solution suggested on last comment but it's not working.

#### EDIT2

Using `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` as parameter for `odbc_connect()` return a `404` nginx error (odbc process die, same error as with pdo). Using `SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER`, returns the specified error (fatal error detail on this post).

Comment: Are you able to try same in a `docker` container? It feels more like your env problems.

Comment: I didn’t tried because that’s my dev env and I doesn’t use docker on it... I have all apps/drivers installed on the OS

Comment: Yea, I believe. Just isolation helps a lot finding such bugs, as we are not able to reproduce your env. Just giving you some hint to solve you the problem.

Comment: I Know I can do a workaround if I use virtualization, containers, or even another machine (for example, windows or *nix ones). But the question are about a problem and a possible fix, not a workaround. I have *nix servers for devel, for testing and for production, but I want to manage a copy on my actual personal devel environment, I'm not trying to revamp all the env.